# How do I make a absolute positioned div have a width equal to it's parent minus some margin

Tags: html, css

I want to have an inner div that sites inside different sized container divs, and starts at a fixed left position and then has a width that fills up the rest of the container.  I've included some example css below to try to get the point across.

I have to use absolute positioning so can't just float right and set a left-margin.  Any ideas of how to make this work with absolute positioning?  I've also tried width: auto and some different box-sizing options.

To clarify, the trickiness of this is that the left border has to be fixed, and the left border has to be against the right border of the container.  I can't use position: relative, and javascript, but I'd probably end up making .inner1 and .inner2 divs with hard-coded widths before doing that.  But hoping to avoid that.

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

 .container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you allowed to use JavaScript

Comment: There's no need to do this in JavaScript.  All the examples below are in CSS.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Just specify all of the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` properties and the box will expand to be at all of those points.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sgSYS/)

Comment: That's cool, so the 0 values are essentially telling the browser to use default?

Comment: @Jeremy: No, it's telling it to position the box 0 length from the top and 0 length from the bottom, which in essence stretches the box from top to bottom. Saying 200px from the left and 0 length from the right stretches the box from the 200px position at the left all the way to the right. Without specifying both sides, it will use the width and/or height the box creates based on its content instead. Note that you don't need to specify "px" for 0. 0 is always 0, no matter what measurement it is in, so we can safely use *just* 0.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get what exactly do you need but why don't you use percentages?

Instead of:

```
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Why don't you use something like:

```
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Setup percentages for left and width attribute accordingly. 40-60, 30-70 and so on.

Hope this helps. If not, please specify a little more.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

This works.  Change the width of the outer box to whatever you want and the inner box grows to match it.

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
} 

.inner {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Edit: [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Qa4J/)

Comment: He asked how to accomplish it with absolute positioning.